# ASP.Net VB Stored procedure allows null parameter - how to pass integer that is NULL to Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures, null, parameter-passing

The value (parameter) of ABC can be NULL.  I'm struggling with how to set it to null.  The statement below is not working.  If I trying to set type Nullable(OfInteger), I get the error that the value is the 'wrong type.'  Thanks in advance.

```
 Dim ABC as Integer = Nothing

 Public Function RunStoredProce(ByVal **ABC** As Integer, ByVal DEF As String) _
               As IEnumerable(Of MyProjectStoredProcResults) Implements MyFunction.GetThatDataResult

        Dim y = (From p In dc.uspReportMyFunction(**ABC**, DEF)
            Select p).ToList

        Return y

    End Function
```

Comment: Is the parameter in the stored procedure declared optional (i.e. `paramName <type> = NULL`)? In that case changing the parameter to `ByVal abc as Nullable(Of Integer)` should work

Comment: Because if the value of ABC is NULL it returns all values of ABC, otherwise it returns the value stored in ABC.  This is handeled in a View.

Comment: The parameter is not declared as OPTIONAL because, I understand it, you MUST assign a default value to an optional parameter.

Comment: That has no bearing on using ToList(). Returning the raw enumerable instead of a materialized list can still enumerate 0 items, 1 item, or many, and may save you needing to load the many items into ram all at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim ABC As Nullable(Of Integer)

Public Function RunStoredProce(ByVal ABC As Nullable(Of Integer), ByVal DEF As String) _
           As IEnumerable(Of MyProjectStoredProcResults) Implements MyFunction.GetThatDataResult

    Dim y = (From p In dc.uspReportMyFunction(ABC, DEF)
        Select p).ToList

    Return y

End Function
```

I believe linqtosql will handle the nullable translation automatically.

Comment: When I run the function I get the following error: "Nullable object must have a value."

Answer (score 0):

You can make the integer nullable, and only pass it in if it has a value:

Notice how `ABC` is being passed in as a `Nullable` type:

```
Public Function RunStoredProce(ByVal ABC As Integer?, ByVal DEF As String) As IEnumerable(Of MyProjectStoredProcResults) Implements MyFunction.GetThatDataResult
    Return (From p In dc.uspReportMyFunction(ABC, DEF) Select p).ToList
End Function
```

I don't know how you're system is set up, but assuming `uspReportMyFunction` is the function that calls the stored procedure, you would want to exclude `ABC` when it's null:

```
If ABC.HasValue Then
    'Add ABC as a parameter
End If

'Add DEF as a parameter

'Execute the stored procedure
```

**EDIT**

Let's say this is the data function that executes the stored procedure

```
public void SaveSomething(int jobID, int? postNumber)
{
    using (var data = new DataAccess(this.ConnectionString))
    {
        data.ProcedureName = "SaveSomething";

        data.AddParm("@JobID", SqlDbType.Int, JobID);
        if (postNumber.HasValue)
            data.AddParm("@PostNumber", SqlDbType.Int, PostNumber.GetValueOrDefault());

        return data.ExecNonQuery();
    }
}
```

From the front end, you could call this function like this:

```
int jobID = 1;
int? postNumber = null;

GetWorkOrderDetailAdjustment(jobID, postNumber); //postNumber == null
```

Comment: When I run the function I get the following error:  "Nullable object must have a value."

Comment: Should I just leave 'ABC' out of the statement:  Dim y = (From p In dc.uspReportMyFunction(ABC, DEF) Select p).ToList......????

Comment: I would leave it in there, and just make it so `dc.uspReportMyFunction` excludes `ABC` from the procedure call if it's null.

Comment: That's a problem because I have an interface defined with both parameters (see Implments statement).

Comment: In the interface, just make sure that parameter accepts a `Nullable` type. You're only excluding the parameter from the database command object.